# Grafana alerting sending multiple notifications

Tags: grafana

I have 2 Instances for Grafana and installed on Openshift clusters.

Followed grafana [guide](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/set-up/configure-high-availability/) and already setup high availability for Grafana alerting but still getting notification from both the instances for each alert. That means getting 2 notifications for each alert.

```
[unified_alerting]
enabled = true
ha_listen_address = ${POD_IP}:9094
ha_peers = grafana-alerting.grafana:9094
ha_advertise_address = ${POD_IP}:9094
```

Also firewall rules are created for 9094 port both on TCP & UDP.

Is any configuration missing?

Already configured HA setup